# How to switch between Perspective and Orthographic cameras keeping size of desired object

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinate-transformation, perspectivecamera, orthographic

I try to switch between Perspective and Orthographic cameras in my script.
I want object on some depth to keep it's projection size.
I gave up to understand the geometry...

**Could you provide some link to a simple tutorial [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html#perspective) is too complicated for me.**

For object with `position.z==0` i have:

```
perspCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W / H, 1, 1000);
perspCamera.position.z = 100;

var S=Math.tan((45/180)*Math.PI)*100;
orthoCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -S, S, S, -S, 1, 1000 );
```

It is incorrect.

## Update:

I get it I will post an answer with codepen link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation between Z-distance and size, at perspective projection is:

```
var fov_y   = 45;
var depht_s = Math.tan(fov_y/2.0 * Math.PI/180.0) * 2.0;
```

[image]

So the orthographic projection has to be ([THREE.OrthographicCamera](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/OrthographicCamera)):

```
var Z      = 100;
var aspect = W / H;
var size_y = depht_s * Z;
var size_x = depht_s * Z * aspect; 

orthoCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    -size_x/2,  size_x/2,
     size_y/2, -size_y/2,
     1, 1000 );
```